# Partially replace WebView content while it is loading

Tags: java, webview, javafx

The thing i want to do is to replace some part(s) of the web page HTML content (that is currently getting loaded inside WebView engine) with my own HTML content.

As a simple example - i want to replace every loaded page body's background color to RED. Meaning i will need to add or replace existing body bgcolor attribute with my own value. What should i do to achieve that?

Here is the basic browser code based on JavaFX WebView component:

```
public class BrowserTest extends Application
{
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        launch ( args );
    }

    public void start ( Stage stage )
    {
        stage.setTitle ( "WebView" );

        Browser browser = new Browser ();
        browser.load ( "http://google.com" );

        Scene scene = new Scene ( browser );
        stage.setScene ( scene );

        stage.show ();
    }

    public class Browser extends Region
    {
        final WebView browser;
        final WebEngine webEngine;

        public Browser ()
        {
            super ();
            browser = new WebView ();
            webEngine = browser.getEngine ();
            getChildren ().add ( browser );
        }

        public void load ( String url )
        {
            webEngine.load ( url );
        }

        private Node createSpacer ()
        {
            Region spacer = new Region ();
            HBox.setHgrow ( spacer, Priority.ALWAYS );
            return spacer;
        }

        protected void layoutChildren ()
        {
            double w = getWidth ();
            double h = getHeight ();
            layoutInArea ( browser, 0, 0, w, h, 0, HPos.CENTER, VPos.CENTER );
        }

        protected double computePrefWidth ( double height )
        {
            return 750;
        }

        protected double computePrefHeight ( double width )
        {
            return 500;
        }
    }
}
```

There was a good example of this technique in some Oracle docs but since last JavaFX and site updates i couldn't find it at all. Maybe anyone has the link to old docs...

**Note:** Also **jewelsea** offered a good way to make post-changes (when the page is loaded), but i need exactly "load-while" solution for my case, so that WebView won't do double job rendering page twice (before and after changes).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add a listener to [the WebEngine document property](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/web/WebEngine.html#documentProperty) and when it changes:

- EITHER modify the Document using the [org.w3c.dom.Document API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Document.html)
- OR modify the Document using the [WebEngine executeScript API](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/web/WebEngine.html#executeScript%28java.lang.String%29)

**Update**

To intercept the html source in flight and potentially modify it before it reaches WebView, you can [implement](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/protocolhandlers/) your own UrlConnection handler.  This is something I have been able to successfully achieve in the past.  See [option 3 of my longish forum post](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2330194) under the id jsmith for some background info and pointers on how to do this.  The key to doing this is setting [URL.setURLStreamHandlerFactory(myHandlerFactory)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#setURLStreamHandlerFactory%28java.net.URLStreamHandlerFactory%29).

Comment: Thanks for the idea about the WebEngine document changes - it does work. But still i was looking for a slightly different solution. To modify the document i need to wait for its load first and the WebView will render the loaded document atleast once. But i want to intercept the document load and modify the incoming data so first WebView rendering result will be the final one. I don't even need any parsed DOM tree to work with - it will be more than fine to work with simple HTML (text) content since i have other tools to parse and modify HTML content.

Comment: Adding to the above idea: you could masquerade the WebView until it's done rendering the second time. This wouldn't fix the "double render", but would prevent the user from seeing the first one

Comment: Added info to answer on intercepting and potentially modifying streams to be loaded into a WebView.

Comment: Thanks, that is a good point to start from. I think my question is answered now :)

Comment: Can you paste down your custom `myHandlerFactory`? The link you referred to in Oracle forum is dead.

Answer (score 2):

It is a little bit late but you may:

1. Load the page (without showing the component on the screen).
2. Change what you want in Document structure.
3. Show stage.

Than changed the content will appear and will start to be visible for user.

Comment: That is an option, but it might delay content display and it is rather a hack than a proper solution in my case. It seems that "intercepting" connection itself is the only viable option to do exactly what I wanted to.